# How to print argv in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to print the argv in a tclsh program. But the following does not work. Could anybody let me know the proper way to print an array in tcl? Thanks.

```
$ cat main.tcl 
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

puts {*}$argv
$ ./main.tcl a b c
bad argument "c": should be "nonewline"
    while executing
"puts {*}$argv"
    (file "./main.tcl" line 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Tcl, `argv` is a list. Since every well behaved value in Tcl has a string representation, it is sufficient to invoke `puts $argv` to see the program arguments shown as space separated words.

Comment: Additionally, `puts` takes only one argument (other than the optional channel or flag)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the options to `puts` created the error message that, though technically correct, doesn't offer much help to resolve the problem, i.e. "bad argument" would not have suggested to me immediately to find out the type of `argv`.

Comment: A newer patch release of 8.5 has a more helpful error message in this case. It's nearly a decade since the error reporting in this area was rewritten so the code producing this message is seriously outdated.